# IBM Message Broker running on linux needs to call windows executable. Can it be done?

Tags: batch-file, messagebroker

The scenarios is:

IBM WMB V8 running on linux has a list of user id's given to it in an MQ message. For each user id I need to connect to a windows box (samba share probably) and then pass this user id to a windows executable i.e.

C:\temp\command.exe 1234
C:\temp\command.exe 5678

the output from this command will return an image of this user from a database output to a directory.

WMB then goes and retrieves this image and somehow maps (user id => image) and updates a database somewhere.

Is this scenario possible in WMB without involving some other processor on the windows machine?

I can't see any nodes to help with this and I'm expecting i'll have to dump the userid list in a file and use perl or similar to process the command & image capture and return these to WMB as a message or something.

Regards,

Sapatos

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a hard task. You can call arbitrary C-code and code custom nodes in C, so it's not impossible, since you could probably do most things with C and the Internet of libraries.

It seems like you would save yourself months of trouble by setting up a simple service on the windows box, for instance something listening to MQ, invokes the command then replies with the image. 
You have not missed any thing. There are not any built in functionallity in WMB for this task. At least not when running on non windows platforms.

Comment: thanks Petter, that's the conclusion I've come to. I'll probably build a java web service on the box to handle the task

Comment: Or you can use XMS on the windows box if you want MQ transport. http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24011756